# Datapipeline can't connect to Redshift

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I've restored a Redshift cluster to EC2 Classic from a snapshot in a VPC. I've transferred my old datapipelines and updated their pipeline definition with the JDBC connection of my new cluster.

However, when I try to rerun a pipeline, it gives the following error:

```
df-041104839VS05ZRRF9GE amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to jdbc:postgresql://adops-etl.cxp7sr869idv.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/staging?tcpKeepAlive=true Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Are there additional configurations I need now that I'm moving from VPC to EC2 Classic with this cluster and pipelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by copying the pipeline definition from an existing pipeline and replacing the details for it with those of my new pipelines. At some point Amazon changed how they structure the pipeline definition JSON, and the difference in formats was somehow leading to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the security group and the rules in the group.
Make sure your ip is allowed with the correct port number to connect to Redshift.
If your connection is SSL based, the endpoint changes.

Comment: I think my problem ended up being unrelated, but thanks for your help @Paladin!